# PHP contact form not sending

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I have a contact form on a page that sends the details of the form to an email address. You can view it here, www.wonder.ie

The HTML for the form is the following:

```
<form id="form" name="form27" class="wufoo  page" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="mailer.php">  
    <ul>
        <li id="foli1">
            <label class="op" id="title1" for="Field1">Name</label>
            <div><input id="Field1" name="name" type="text" class="op required" value="" maxlength="255" tabindex="1" onkeyup="handleInput(this);" onchange="handleInput(this);" /></div>  
        </li>

        <li id="foli2">
        <label class="op" id="title2" for="Field2">Email</label>
            <div><input id="Field2" name="email" type="text" class="op required email" value="" maxlength="255" tabindex="2" onkeyup="handleInput(this);" onchange="handleInput(this);" /></div>
        </li>

        <li id="foli3">
            <label class="op" id="title3" for="Field3">Inquiry</label>
            <div><textarea id="Field3" name="message" class="op required" rows="10" cols="50" tabindex="3" onkeyup="handleInput(this);" onchange="handleInput(this);"></textarea></div>
        </li>
        </ul>  
        <input id="button" name="saveForm" class="btTxt submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />         
</form>
```

And for my PHP it is this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$to = "AN_EMAIL@ADDRESS.COM";
$subject = "Email from Wonder.ie";
$name_field = $_POST['name'];
$email_field = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Message:\n $message";

mail($to, $subject, $body);
} else {
echo "blarg!";
}
?>
```

Does everything look correct? I know I have the form names matched correctly with the PHP but I can't figure out why I'm not receiving the email you know - FYI the PHP on the site has a real email address, not AN_EMAIL@ADDRESS.COM. Once I hit the submit button I am taken to mailer.php but I notice the echo "blarg!" so my guess is the email is not being sent.

Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

You should change

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['saveForm'])) {
```

Comment: This is 100% right; when you access variables in $_POST they are labled via the name attribute of the form element.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['saveForm'])) {
```

This is because $_POST looks for the name of a form input, not the type.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing above helps, try and see if you can debug the code.

[Catching PHP mail() errors and showing reasonable user error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913817/catching-php-mail-errors-and-showing-reasonable-user-error-message)

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP code you check if `$_POST['submit']` is set, but in your HTML code you gave the submit button the name of `saveForm` so you should change the line

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['saveForm'])) {
```

Hope this helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

In your html your have

```
<input id="button" name="saveForm" class="btTxt submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

but in the php file when you check for `$_POST["submit"]`, which is not right.

You need to change `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` to `if(isset($_POST['saveForm']))`

or `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` to `if(isset($_POST))`

Answer (score 0):

Some email servers won't accept emails without appropriate headers and you haven't provided any.  This is what I use.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
$header = "From: ".$fromText."\r\n";
$header .= "Cc: ".$ccText."\n";
$header .= "Reply-To : ".$fromText."\r\n";
$header .= "Return-Path : ".$fromText."\r\n";
$header .= "X-Mailer: PHP\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
mail($toText, $subjectText, $msgText, $header, '-f'.$fromText);
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is it's pour out blarg.
it's definitely the post does not reach your

> code->

`mail($to, $subject, $body);`

and the name of the submit should be changed to

> 'saveForm'

by the way :)..

just tried

```
mail($to, $subject, $body);
```

in your `x.php` , upload it and chage to , subject and body to right things
and if it's sent then the mail function works okay.

```
 if(@mail($emailRecipient, $subject, $message, $headers))
    {
      echo "Mail Sent Successfully";
    }else{
      echo "Mail Not Sent";
    }
```

this is also a good code I have found in stackoverflow
to check if mail function works.

Answer (score 0):

you are using
 `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {`
 
 but, you have save the submit button name as`saveForm` 
 So, use  
`if(isset($_POST['saveForm'])) {`

Answer (score -1):

HTML form mail sending guide in PHP http://top-answers.net/webhost/web-hosting.html