# PHP mail $email = $_POST['email'] in $recipients

Tags: php

I have the following php mail file :

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$choice = $_POST['choice'];$num = $_POST['num'];
$choice1 = $_POST['choice1'];$num1 = $_POST['num1'];
$phone= $_POST['phone'];
$town= $_POST['town'];
$formcontent="
Name: $name \n
Number: $phone \n
Choice: $choice Amount:$num
Choice: $choice1 Amount:$num1
Town: $town \n
Email: $email" ;
$recipient = "info@domain.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";?>
```

Can I add the $email to the recipients? I want to add the email entered in the form into the recipients that receive the email. (info@domain.com and the email entered in the form ($email = $_POST['email'];) will receive the email.

Comment: Comma-separate them, `"info@domain.com,".$email`; However, you're going to want to make sure you sanitize the data coming from your form - otherwise, you're going to have spam-bots abusing that thing the second the first one finds it.

Comment: Its not working still..its saying Error

Comment: The code above works fine. Try removing the `or die("Error!");` and see what kind of error you get and let us know.

Comment: It just doesnt send. It say the thank you but no email is received at all. Not even on the original one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add multiple email addresses to `$recipient` by separating them with commas. Try this.

```
$recipient = "info@domain.com, $email";
```

**Edit**

Here is the whole thing.

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $choice = $_POST['choice']; $num = $_POST['num'];
    $choice1 = $_POST['choice1']; $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
    $phone= $_POST['phone'];
    $town= $_POST['town'];

    $formcontent = "
    Name: $name \n
    Number: $phone \n
    Choice: $choice Amount:$num
    Choice: $choice1 Amount:$num1
    Town: $town \n
    Email: $email";

    $recipient = "info@domain.com, $email";
    $subject = "Contact Form";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    echo "Thank you";

?>
```

Comment: Hmmm. Are you sure all of the values are being posted? See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913817/catching-php-mail-errors-and-showing-reasonable-user-error-message.

Comment: I'm not sure what to say. It works for me when using the code above. Copy and paste the whole block of code into the PHP file.